# C++ template operator not found as match

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-overloading, iterable

I'm trying to create a general `operator<<` for `std::ostream` and any Iterable type.

This is the code:

```
template <class T,template<class> class Iterable> inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s,const Iterable<T>& iter){
    s << "[ ";
    bool first=false;
    for(T& e : iter){
        if(first){
            first=false;
            s << e;
        }else{
            s << ", " << e;
        }
    }
    s << " ]";
    return s;
}
```

Unfortunately my operator is not found as a match for a `vector<uint>` and the compiler tries to match with `operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)` .

Any idea how I can change the overload to be recognized?

Comment: Another problem is that you try to iterate over a `const` container using a non-const `T&`. Use `T&&` or `T const&` instead.

Comment: Also you should initialize first to true

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The direct solution to your problem is that `vector` is a template on *two* types, not one, so you'd want to write:

```
template <typename... T, template <typename... > class Iterable>
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Iterable<T...>& iter)
{
    s << "[ ";
    bool first = true; // not false
    for (const auto& e : iter) {
        // rest as before
    }
    return s << " ]";
}
```

That works, but is a little unsatisfying - since some things that are templates aren't iterable and some things that aren't templates are. Furthermore, we do not actually need either `Iterable` or `T` in our solution. So how about we write something that takes any Range - where we define Range as something that has a `begin()` and `end()`:

```
template <typename Range>
auto operator<<(std::ostream& s, const Range& range) 
-> decltype(void(range.begin()), void(range.end()), s)
{
    // as above, except our container is now named 'range'
}
```

If that's *too* general, then you can do:

```
template <typename T> struct is_range : std::false_type;
template <typename T, typename A>
struct is_range<std::vector<T,A>> : std::true_type;
// etc.

template <typename Range>
typename std::enable_if<
    is_range<Range>::value,
    std::ostream&
>::type
operator<<(std::ostream& s, const Range& range)
```

Comment: thanks. unfortunately this doesnt work for me, maybe because the operator is too general. ill get a lot of errors like `ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::stringstream {aka std::basic_stringstream<char>}' and 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}'` because `string` has begin() and end().

Comment: You can just write a `typename std::enable_if<is_container<CONTAINER>::value, std::ostream&>::type` and provide a type trait for `is_container` that does what you want.

Comment: @Barry I'd rather use the name `Range`, even though that isn't standardized yet. We do have the requirements from the range-based for loop, though, and can emulate something similar by using free `begin` and `end` functions (plus lookup tricks).

Comment: @dyp Renamed to `Range`, I like that.